# Arangodb traversal to include head vertex

Tags: graph, arangodb

I'm using GRAPH_TRAVERSAL to get the path from a list of nodes to the head of the tree.  This works perfectly except when the example happens to be the head of the tree.  In this case, the edgeCollection doesn't have an inbound entry for this object so it doesn't appear in the results.

```
FOR v IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('gdp2',
                         [{_id:'pmsite/14419285155'}],
                         'inbound',{edgeCollection:'child'})
       RETURN v
```

The result is an empty list: `[]`

Is there a way I can guarantee that the starting node is on the list?  It would be a pain to go through the list of examples to segregate which ones are at the head of a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the query itself. It contains a subtle error which is hard to spot:

```
[{_id:pmsite/14419285155}],
```

This is missing the quotes around `pmsite/14419285155`.

What this query realy does is to devide (probably the count of) the collection `pmsite` by the id `14419285155` and put in this as `{_id: divcount}`.

If you add the missing quotes, the query should do exactly what you want there. (**edit**: quotes were present in the original query, fixed the post.)

hint: `db._explain()` gives information about that.

Trying to reproduce, using the [knows sample graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html#the-knowsgraph):

```
arangosh> var examples = require("org/arangodb/graph-examples/example-graph.js");
arangosh> var g = examples.loadGraph("knows_graph");


arangosh> db._query("FOR e IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('knows_graph', [{_id: 'persons/eve'}], 'inbound', {edgeCollection: 'knows'}) return e").toArray()
[ 
  [ 
    { 
      "vertex" : { 
        "_id" : "persons/eve", 
        "_rev" : "1405497100114", 
        "_key" : "eve", 
        "name" : "Eve" 
      } 
    } 
  ] 
]
```

However what creates a somewhat similar behaviour is to use a collection not part of the graph definition:

```
arangosh> db._create("othercol")
arangosh> db.othercol.save({_key: "1" })
arangosh> db._query("FOR e IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('knows_graph', [{_id: 'othercol/1'}], 'inbound', {edgeCollection: 'knows'}) return e").toArray()
[ ]
```

As pointed out in the Comments, edge relations have a direction. If you want to have edges pointing in both directions, you need to create a second relation in the other direction. Edges not fullfilling the edge definitions may be ignored.

Comment: That was my error when cleaning up the entry.  It really was quoted. Here is a true copy/paste version:


    FOR e IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('gdp2_graph',[{_id:'pmsite/14842647715'}],'inbound',{edgeCollection:'pm_child'}) return e

The result was an empty array: []

Comment: FOR v IN pmsite FILTER v._key == '14842647715' return v

Returns the structure

[
  {
    "protocol": "p4+icm",
    "name": "site1",
    "kind": "site",
    "model": "oldGDP",
    "connection": "localhost:1680",
    "uri": "$(site:protocol)://$(site:connection)/depot/icm/proj/$(project)/$(variant)/$(vartype:dir)/$(library)/...",
    "_id": "pmsite/14842647715",
    "_rev": "14842647715",
    "_key": "14842647715"
  }
]

Comment: I've edited the post, maybe the collection could be the problem? Also cut'n'pasting your messages gave me some realy weird control-characters in `edgeCollection`

Comment: That was my first thought, to check the collection definition.  I have pmsite in the fromCollection but not the toCollection.  Since this is the head of the tree, it seems that this is right.  Or do I have a misunderstanding?

Comment: Putting pmsite on both the from and to collection lists solved this problem but would this be a bug?

Comment: No, its a feature - definitely. The `edge-definition`s are loaded early in the query cycle and can shorten queries. Inserting edges that don't fit the edge definition will be denied by the *named graph* functions in first place.

Comment: What I meant was, if the collection is in fromCollection wouldn't that be enough to return the item when using inbound?  Why do I need it in both fromCollection and toCollection for it to show up?

Comment: edge definitions have a direction - so if you want to have edges pointing from and to some vertex collection, you need to define two relations for that.

Comment: Is you question answered hereby? if yes, can you mark the answer as accepted? if not, whats missing?

Comment: You may have answered my question, but my understanding may be flawed.  Am I right in assuming that when you use "outbound" it selects from the "from" edge property and when you use "inbound" it selects from the "to" edge property?  If this is the case, I don't understand why I needed to add the item on the "from" edge collection on the "to" edge collection for "inbound" when the collection is only found on the "from" properties.  This is why I believe this may be a bug.

Comment: are you messing up vertex and edge collections in your assumption?

Comment: Possibly.  Are you saying that the only way to traverse in direction (from parent to child and visa verse) through an edge is to have the vertex types on both sides of the edge definitions?  This just seems counter-intuitive, what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: In arangoDB you can also make an edge point directly to another edge. But - pun intendet - thats an edge case. Usually edges `_from` and `_to` point to vertex documents in vertex collections.

Comment: Let's see if I can phase the problem in another way.  Suppose we have class A, class B, and class C.  We add a "child" edge from A to B and from B to C.  In our edge definition we have A and B in the from list and B and C in the to list.

Traversing down the edges from B via outbound we get B and C.  Traversing up the edges from B via inbound we get B but not A.  In order to get A, A must also be added to the edge definition "from" list.  This just doesn't seem right.  What am I missing?

Comment: an edge as the edge definition is always a pair: (source, destination). Try [loading the city graph example](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html#the-city-graph) and have a look at `db._graphs.toArray()` where the edge definitions are currently stored. `InterationalHighway` connects several vertex collections.